# How to convert the output of an .aspx into a JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, json, parsing

I need to convert the output of an .aspx page into a JSON object (due to a JSONP Ajax request).

In fact with this page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="folder_mypage" %>

<div class="myClass">Hello</div>
```

with jQuery, after the ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myownajax.projects.it/folder/mypage.aspx',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("it is ok");
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    }                
});
```

I get `parsererror - SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier`
That's why I need to convert "the output of the page" to JSON element.

How can I do it?

**EDIT**
In less words : I want to append an .aspx context to an element, client side! The request is cross-doman, that's why I need JSONP, which needed JSON as result! So, what I'm looking for is just this : take the HTML (as a string) and put in a JSON object. Like `result.myHtmlString="<div class='myClass'>Hello</div>";`

Comment: after reading the other answer and your comment, maybe you are looking for how to implement something like this? http://json.fastfrag.org/

Comment: Not really! That string is "parsed" into JSON object! What I need is to take the whole HTML and put it (as string) like result.myHtmlString="<div class='myClass'>Hello</div>";

Comment: Do you understand now what I need?

Comment: my answer shows you how to do that. you should get an object `{ Html: "<html><head>...</html>" }`

Comment: { html: "<div class='myClass'>Hello</div>" }

Comment: Yeah, but how can I get that object on C#? That's what I ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this (not tested, never used it myself, but it shows the general gist and the js-serializer)

```
class Result{
  public String Html{get;set;}
}

TextReader txtread = new TextReader("page.aspx");
string text = txtread.ReadToEnd();
var res = new Result(){Html=text};
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(res);
```

Without using Serializer:

```
String html = new TextReader("page.aspx").ReadToEnd();
String json = "{ Html: '" + html + "'}";
return json;
```

json is a string!

Comment: Oh...ok, just this! Damn, I get this error on jQuery, after the calling... `parsererror - Error: jQuery1710912841784877329_1330084304383 was not called`

Comment: looks like a new question. just accept this one, and post a new question and make sure to include the code that produces the error. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should note that your result page isn't in `JSON`, but in `HTML`:

```
<div class="myClass">Hello</div>
```

In JSON it would be something like this:

```
{
    "div": 
    { 
        myclass: "John"
    },
    ...
}
```

So you can move your logic to the codebehind, or try to find some renderers.
Currently it is hard to say what are you trying to do - return a HTML via JSON?

**UPDATE:**
If you want to return the HTML to the client, simply wrap it like this:

```
{
    html: "YOUR RESULT HTML HERE"
}
```

Comment: Eh, yeah! What I'm looking for is this : convert the result page (HTML) to JSON, so I can just manage it client side! I think the whole HTML as a string, and insert into JSON object?

Comment: I want to append an .aspx context to an element, client side! The request is cross-doman, that's why I need JSONP, which needed JSON as result! So, what I'm looking for is just this : take the HTML (as a string) and put in a JSON object. Like result.myHtmlString="<div class='myClass'>Hello</div>";

Comment: How can "I Wrap it" like that on C#?